# How to change div by pressing keyboard key S?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, keyboard

I have two divs

```
<div class="summary">Summary</div>

<div class="summary-cont"><p>Content...</p></div>
```

The div "summary-cont" is hidden, display: none;

I want to work it like this: I press in keyboard button "S" then div "summary" hides and shows div "summary-cont"

Anybody know how to do this with javascript?

Here is the working code:

```
<script>
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 83) { $('.summary').hide(); }     // S
  if (e.keyCode == 83) { $('.summary-cont').show(); }   // S
});
</script>
```

Comment: A quick google search for js keypress events would give you the answer

Comment: Can you post the [**code you have tried**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) please? We can have a look at it and see what to change to get it to work.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl from the wording in the question, its doubtful this person tried anything.

Comment: @JeffShaver, it is sarcasm ;)

Comment: The question seems okay to me.

Answer (score 7):

This will do for you for either `S` or `s` character.

Using `Javascript`

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) { // or document.onkeypress
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 115 || e.keyCode == 83) {
        alert("do something");
    }
};
```

Using `jQuery` library.  If you have any `input` box.

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 115 || code == 83) { //Keycode for alphabets S(83) & s(115)
       //Do something (show your div)
    }
});
```

For solution without `input` box you can try this one.

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 115 || code == 83) { //Keycode for alphabets S(83) & s(115)
       //Do something (show your div)
    }
});
```

Comment: Seeing OP tagged question with JavaScript and not jQuery you should propably provide a JavaScript solution as well and also mention that the code you provided at this time is a jQuery specific solution.

Comment: You got it wrong :) He don't want to input "s" letter anywhere, just to press keyboard button "s".

Comment: Sigh... the person never said anything about using jQuery.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: Yeah, you got wrong, no inputs will be used, only keyboard button S, really i don't have an example code right now.

Comment: It is Javascript using JQuery library, he specified that - it's a good answer - more than the question deserves too.

Comment: I don't know why the answer is downvoted. 
If you take a look at the phrases carefully, Ive specified jquery library and also used phrase "if you have any input box". Glad for the negative vote though which I receive for trying to provide a solution and help atleast.

Comment: So i can change 'input' to div name , ex.: "primmary-cont" ?

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Glad some one read my answer carefully

Comment: @Yegya, see, that is not a good answer. He just want to open site, and after pressing "s" key get desired effect.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I think he is smart enough to search for the keyCode for big alphabet S. The answer was intented to provide him atleast some idea.

Comment: @Yegya: I downvoted as the question was asking for a JavaScript solution and though OP might well be accepting a jQuery solution the answer lacks to answer the question using JavaScript without jQuery. The answer should contain a JavaScript only solution as well to be an acceptable answer. In my humble oppinion as this could be for homework, for a project not allowing jQuery or similar.

Comment: @user2208097 I'm afraid to say, you cant just replace input with div. You have to search a little more for the key input without any input boxes.

Comment: @Yegya, why for God sake, you insist on inputs :) Use window, document... Don't complicate it.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Not an excuse, but you can count me as a newbie on stackoverflow though I joined 10 months ago, I just started answering and my bad that I've not gone though or properly understood the rules on stackoverflow. Anyway that was a nice explaination. Appreciated.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović You'r right. But no need of overreaction by putting the word GOD in this scenario. As I already told, I just tried to provide him some hint on how things work. And yea you are right using window, document in his case is a better approach.

Comment: @Yegya: I don't know if it is a rule on SO but it is my personal opinion. If JavaScript is tagged and not jQuery I personally assume OP is looking for a JavaScript only solution. So I would provide an answer for such. In addition I might recommend using jQuery instead and *in addition* include a jQuery solution. What if the question is for example for a project not allowing jQuery or even homework? You can't turn around to your teacher and tell him to use jQuery instead.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Agreed completely. Though it was just a small try for help. And after his response, I'm quite sure he is not concerned with either jquery or javascript. He just wanted an answer by any means.

Comment: See my code on top, maybe anybody helps me.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl He just posted his code. And by any means I don't see that as a core javascript. His posted code are a jquery sample I guess. So now what do u say about my response. It does deserve some respect I guess. As i illustrated early, the asker is unsure of the particular code use (He can use either javascript solution or jquery solution). My answer deserve some upvote tbh.

Comment: Now I will upvote his question, and your answer (if you edit it and apply on document or window instead on input) :) P.S. Sorry about "God", i'm learning English from movies and internet only, and that is just phrase to me :)

Comment: @Yegya: Now that OP changed question from `Anybody know how to do this with javascript?`, showing code whcih uses jQuery you are absolutly right as this is a completly different scenario. I off course will remove my down vote in that case. ...and add +1 for including the `document` solution :)

Comment: @user2208097 Ive edited an answer for you. Hope it helps. For particular summary-content pair (if you have multiple divs), you need to do some additional work though.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović OOps, I already applied document before even noticing your suggestion. thanks for the suggestion though.